# laravel multi forms route

Tags: php, laravel-5

everybody, I have a multi form on the same page and same route all things are working fine but only last form is working

```
   Route::post('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@Update_info');
   Route::post('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@SaveSettings');
   Route::post('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@Update_security');
```

So if I need SaveSettings
I must change it to

```
Route::post('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@Update_info');
Route::post('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@SaveSettings');
Route::post('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@Update_security');
```

Comment: Where's the difference between those two? And I'd suggest using different routes for different actions. How is your app going to decide which controller/action to take when your route is hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a name to your routes, then use it in your forms

```
Route::post('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@Update_info')->name("update.info");
Route::post('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@SaveSettings')->name("save.settings");
Route::post('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@Update_security')->name("update.security");

<form action="{{route("update.security",$user)"}}>
<form action="{{route("update.info",$user)"}}>
<form action="{{route("save.settings",$user)"}}>
```

So laravel doesn't get confuse which form gonna execute by which controller/method

Comment: why did you add.  .  save.settings  not save_settings

Comment: i'm getting this error "Missing required parameters for [Route: update.info] [URI: user/{user}/settings]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Dev-College\DevCollege\resources\views\User_blade\setti ▶"

Comment: @KareemElsharkawy  hey kareem, sorry I forgot to mention that you should pass user parameter when using these route names. Because in your defined you said each has user parameter